# JSF not updating certain backing bean properties

Tags: jsf, backing-beans

I'm working in a project wich uses JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces 2.2 .
Currently we're working with a wizard (PrimeFaces component) that will guide the user through the registration process. We have 4 steps in the wizard.

Here's the problem: in the first Step the user enters his/her personal details and that got updated correctly in the backing bean.
Step 2 is just a bunch of text and Step 3 presents another form to enter extra information.

But in step 3 the data isn't updated in the backing bean and the properties remains null.
I've tried some workarounds but nothing changed...

Well, here is the relevant parts of the code:

```
            <p:tab id="three" title="Passo 3" >
                       <p:panel header="Sua saúde financeira">
                            <p:messages  />
                             <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5" columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="Você possui alguma reserva? (Dinheiro não investido, coloque 0,00 se não tiver reserva) " />
                                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5" columns="2">
                                    <p:inputText id="reserva" value="#{userWizard.actualMoneyReserve}" size="5" required="true" /> <h:outputText value=" reais." />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <h:outputText value="Qual o valor que você planeja investir por mês? (0,00 se não tiver um planejamento) " />
                                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5" columns="2">
                                    <p:inputText id="valormensal" value="#{userWizard.monthlyInvestment}" size="5" required="true" /> <h:outputText value=" reais." />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <h:outputText value="Qual o valor do seu salário atual?  " />
                                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5" columns="2">
                                    <p:inputText id="salario" value="#{userWizard.salary}" size="5" required="true" /> <h:outputText value=" reais." />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <h:outputText value="Quanto você gasta por mês ?  " />
                                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5" columns="2">
                                    <p:inputText id="gastomensal" value="#{userWizard.lifeCost}" size="5" required="true" /> <h:outputText value=" reais." />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
```

This is from the view, and the backing bean:

```
        private String actualMoneyReserve;
    private String monthlyInvestment;
    private String salary;
    private String lifeCost;    public void save() {
    //Persist user

    this.moneyHealth.setActualMoneyReserve(actualMoneyReserve);
    this.moneyHealth.setLifeCost(lifeCost);
    this.moneyHealth.setMonthlyInvestment(monthlyInvestment);
    this.moneyHealth.setSalary(salary);

    this.user.setMoneyHealth(this.moneyHealth);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.actualMoneyReserve);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.moneyHealth.getActualMoneyReserve());

    GenericDAO<User> gd = new GenericDAO<User>(User.class);
    gd.persist(user);
}
```

I've already exhausted all possible solutions... So please if someone have at least a vague idea, it's valid.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to naildown the root cause with the information given as far. At least one possible cause: one of the parent components of the input fields has a `rendered` attribtue which evaluated `false` at the point the input values are to be gathered. Ensure that the `rendered` condition evaluates the same during form submit as it did during form display.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I ensure that? But, I'm not sure if this is the problem since the other step works normally.